# How can I make sftp accounts that can only access their home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, administration

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.10.

I need to setup 6 accounts for users that will exclusively need sftp. When the user logs in, I need them to only have access to their home directory. I don't want them to be able to navigate to any other places in the file system. I need their ability to type commands to be limited to only the commands needed to view and transfer files back and forth to their home directory.

Can anyone offer some guidance on setting things up this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590) for Debian, which should work perfectly for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

We recently had the same issue but also needed to allow ftp and scp access with the users chrooted to their home directories.

We used [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org) with the mod_sftp plug-in, net2ftp as a front-end to the ftp server, Sun's DSEE7 for user accounts (openldap with the posix schema would work too), and the OS's auto-mounter to mount home directories.

If only need sftp with local accounts then Cry Havok's solution is good, it was the first one we tested with.